# References for Patterning Speed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Imagine I have a system describing two species concentrations $x$ and $y$ defined on a ring of $N$ cells, given by
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_j&=F_x(x_j,\{x_{r}\},y_j,\{y_{r}\})\\
\dot{y}_j&=F_y(x_j,\{x_{r}\},y_j,\{y_{r}\})
\end{align}
for each cell $1\leq j\leq N$, where $\{x_{r}\}$ and $\{y_{r}\}$ are the sets of all the variables of cells that are not cell $j$, and $F_x,F_y$ are general non-linear functions.

For example, consider the system
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_j&=F_x(x_j,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},y_j,y_{j-1},y_{j+1})\\
\dot{y}_j&=F_y(x_j,x_{j-1},x_{j+1},y_j,y_{j-1},y_{j+1})
\end{align}
where we assume dependence on the species concentrations in the immediate neighbours of cell $j$.

Assume we perturb this system around the homogeneous steady state and assume we converge to a patterned solution (I'm skipping many steps here, but essentially we may look at the fastest growing modes, upon a Fourier transform, in order to predict the final pattern, please [check this](http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/%7Ehsg/414/files/lectures/linear-stability-notes.pdf) for a brief introduction on linear stability analysis).

Is it possible, via linear stability analysis, to predict the **speed or time taken to develop a pattern**? I have been trying to look for references and methods in the literature, but with no success so far. Naturally this depends a lot on the shapes of $F_x$ and $F_y$, but I'm wondering what can, in general, be said about the patterning speed (or to reach a certain threshold value).

Comment: Re: "I'm skipping many steps here". It would probably be helpful for you to expand on what you mean by "perturb this system around the homogeneous steady state" and "patterned solution".

Comment: @parsiad This is standard linear stability analysis, but I've edited the question to include some notes as a reference. A "patterned solution" should be understood as any steady state (up to a threshold) obtained by destabilisation of the homogeneous steady state (that is, perturbations that do not decay in time). My main question is regarding the speed of patterning and what can be said about it via standard linear stability analysis. The concept of "peak competition" might come in handy, but I'm not too sure how to relate it to speed yet.